# SQL Server 2008 R2 Choose Certain Rows on Certain Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

EDIT: I'm sorry, the items shouldn't be A and B, they are both A. However, when they have different in_date, they are considered different. So, I have edited my question accordingly.

I have a problem. See the table below:

```
Item | In_Date | Qty_Balance | Created_At
-----+---------+-------------+---------------------------    
A    | 1       | 90          | 2018-09-26 16:09:26.523
A    | 1       | 96          | 2018-09-26 15:26:12.507
A    | 2       | 50          | 2018-09-26 15:24:43.617
A    | 2       | 45          | 2018-09-24 15:47:40.977
```

As you can see, the table is ordered by column "Created_At" desc. Now, what I need is to get the "Qty_Balance" data but only the last entered one for each item. So, for A, I need to get the "Qty_Balance" of 90 whereas for B, I need to get the "Qty_Balance" of 50. We can tell which data is last entered by referring to the "Created_At" column, which is why the column is ordered descending. So, just to be clear, what I need is:

```
Item | In_Date | Qty_Balance | Created_At
-----+---------+-------------+-------------------------    
A    | 1       | 90          | 2018-09-26 16:09:26.523
A    | 2       | 50          | 2018-09-26 15:24:43.617
```

How can I possibly achieve this? Please kindly help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) make a group from `In_Date`, to make row number `order by Created_At DESC`, then get row number is `1` rows.

```
Select 
    Item , 
    In_Date ,
    Qty_Balance , 
    Created_At
from (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY In_Date ORDER BY Created_At DESC) rn
    FROM T
)t1 
where rn = 1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdc9a94725453f39d7f140e037eaa459)

**NOTE**

- `ROW_NUMBER` function make row number.
- `Window function` determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the associated window function is applied.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick response. However, this doesn't seem to solve my problem. I am not getting what I need.

Comment: I edit you can try it, because you edit your sample data.

Comment: Hi there, thanks again for the quick response, I appreciate it, really. This seems to have solved my problem. However, if you don't mind me asking, what does that "rn=1" do exactly? I mean, why use "where rn=1"? Just curious. Thank you again, really. You made my day! :)

Comment: @RchLuvSlly I add more explain hope can help you.  `rn ` are row number make from subquery.

Comment: "rn" is the name for "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY In_Date ORDER BY Created_At DESC)". So basically you are getting the row number 1 of each partition.